# How can I build and install my app created in react-native locally on my android as standalone?

Tags: android, deployment, build, react-native, release

I have created an app with react-native which Im not intending to upload to Play. Im only going to use it locally on my phone. Im getting a very unstable build of my reactnative app and wounder if Im using the right steps

This is what I have done so far:

1. Creating the app with react-native-cli (not expo)
2. After finished the project I open the android folder in Android studio
3. Build -> Generate signed bundle and are going through the process for building an APK
4. Downloading the files in: android\app\release into my phone and install it by running the app-arm64-v8a-release.apk or app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk

The app runs for 10 second and then it crashes!

I have also tried simply runned it on my device with `react-native run-android` but that doesnt seem to bring my assets. The app is basically running some videoclips which doesnt seem to be included with `react-native run-android`

How can I properly install this react-native app on my phone?

Comment: `app-x86_64-release.apk` is for Intel based devices - is your phone running Intel or ARM?

Comment: sorry. It is actually app-arm64-v8a-release.apk and app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk

both of them works. It runs on arm